# UIDatePicker: help to convert pseudo code into objc code

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, pseudocode

I am trying to implement some pseudo code I have for the date picker. However I am unsure of how to add a minute value to adjust an NSDate object.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
//minTime is an NSDate object
minTime = currentTime + 30mins - (currentTime % 15)
```

`(currentTime % 15)` means that the user can only select in 15mins intervals, and must be 15mins from the current 15min interval. For example, if its 10:50, the user should only be able to select 11:15 from the UIDatePicker. If is 10:20, the user should only be able to select 10:45.

I know how to get the currentTime using `[NSDate date]` but I do not know how to add mins to it and adjust it.

Comment: What does "currentTime % 15" mean in the context of time?

Comment: @LeoNatan I must find the modulo of the current time with 15. 15 is 15mins

Comment: But what does that mean? Say "16:45". 16:45+30min = 17:15. What does 16:45 % 15 mean?

Comment: @LeoNatan Sorry about that, The user can only select in 15mins intervals, and must be 15mins from the current 15min interval. For example, if its 10:50, the user should only be able to select 11:15 from the `UIDatePicker`. If is 10:20, the user should only be able to select 10:45. Is this helpful?

Comment: Yes. Edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @LeoNatan I felt the pseudo code was enough. Thanks for tip, ill do that now.

Comment: Please pick one of the answers if they have helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not considered good practice to work with time intervals when working with dates and times. The best solution is to use `NSDateComponents` to add time periods.

```
NSDateComponents* dc = [NSDateComponents new];
dc.minutes = 15;

NSDate* newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dc toDate:oldDate options:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add some minutes to a NSDate using :

```
NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *nowDateAnd2moreMinutes = [nowDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:2*60]; //This add 2 minutes (2 * 60sec)
```

More information [in apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/dateByAddingTimeInterval%3a).

Edit I wrote a little function that add minutes :

```
+(NSDate) addMinutes:(int) minutes toDate:(NSDate) date{
    return [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:minutes*60];
}
```

Bonus : Function that add minutes and seconds to a date

```
+(NSDate) addMinutes:(int) minutes andSeconds:(int) sec toDate:(NSDate) date{
    return [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:(minutes*60)+sec];
}
```

Comment: It's better to use NSDateComponents instead of seconds you calculate yourself.